# How to use aggregation on spring boot with mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongotemplate, spring-repositories

I am trying to get array list of specific field using aggregate function. I am trying to run below mongodb query:

```
db.txn.aggregate([
{ "$match" : { "name" : "piyush"}} ,
{ "$group" : { "_id" : null , "idList" : { "$push" : "$_id"}}} ,
{ "$project" : { "idList" : 1}}
])
```

It will return me below result:

```
{
"_id" : null,
"idList" : [ 
    ObjectId("5c150672ec78951f4c1cff00"), 
    ObjectId("5c150673ec78951f4c1cff01"), 
    ObjectId("5c150673ec78951f4c1cff02")
]}
```

I want to implement same query using spring boot framework with mongodb so how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this :

```
Aggregation aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        match(Criteria.where("name").is("Piyush")),
        group("_id").push("_id").as("idList")
        project("idList")
    );
```

You can refer more details here :

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: it will return me result as : [
 {
  _id=5c150673ec78951f4c1cff01, 
  idList=[5c150673ec78951f4c1cff01]
 }, 
 {
  _id=5c150673ec78951f4c1cff02, 
  idList=[5c150673ec78951f4c1cff02]
 }, 
 {
  _id=5c150672ec78951f4c1cff00, 
  idList=[5c150672ec78951f4c1cff00]
 }
] any it to set _id as null in group Operation?